# Only assign property if defined

Tags: javascript

I have the following variable:

```
const quote = {
    author: req.body.author,
    quote: req.body.quote,
    source: req.body.source,
    updatedAt: Date.now(),
  };
```

I only want to assign the values if they are defined. For example I can check for undefined with:

```
 if(req.body.author === undefined) {
    console.log('author undefined');
  }
```

But how do I translate this to not assigning the value? Do I need to check afterwards and then remove the property if `undefined`?

Comment: `author: req.body.author || null` and yes, you can check afterwards

Comment: Have you decided what you want those property values to be when the source values are not defined?

Comment: Basically I don't want the values to be there. These are from a function that later on writes the values into a database. If I get the values in the PUT request I want to update them, if I don;t get them, I want to leave them as they are.

Comment: Then you'll have to construct the object with a set of `if` statements. It seems pretty obvious really; you've got such an `if` statement in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not just use default values and set them to null if the property is undefined in the post data?

```
//Unsure if you want the default value to have any meaning
//using null would likely achieve what you're asking.
var default_value = null;

const quote = {
    author: req.body.author || default_value,
    quote: req.body.quote || default_value,
    source: req.body.source || default_value,
    updatedAt: Date.now(),
};
```

If you really want to strip them, here's a basic loop you could use after.

```
for (var i in quote) {
       if (quote[i] == default_value) {
           //Unsure how this works with const... might have to change to var
           delete quote[i];
       }
   }
```

Alternatively you could iterate over the req.body object and avoid having to validate after the initial declaration.

```
var quote = {};

for (var i in req.body) {
    quote[i] = req.body[i];
}
```

Unsure if you would still want to validate against certain values in the req.body object so you could add a check for them being null/undefined

```
var quote = {};

for (var i in req.body) {

   //This will only declare the value on the quote object if the value
   //is not null or undefined. False could be a value you're after so
   //I avoided using the cleaner version of 'if (!req.body[i]) ...'
   if (req.body[i] !== null || req.body[i] !== undefined) { 
      quote[i] = req.body[i];
   }
}
```

You could even break that out into a nice reusable function (basic implementation below):

```
//Obj would be your post data
//bad_values would be an array of values you're not interested in.
function validatePOST (obj, bad_values) {

     var data = {};

     for (var i in obj) {

         //Check the value isn't in the array of bad values
         if (bad_values.indexOf(obj[i]) === -1) {

             data[i] = obj[i];
         }
     }

     //Return the validated object
     return data;
}
```

Now you could use this in all of your routes.

```
var quote = validatePOST(req.body, [null, undefined]);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the 'default' values are written in my database. So if there is nothing in the request, I don't want the property to be there (because it will get overwritten). So this will just set the new values in my database to null if not provided.

Comment: Check the loop I just posted

Comment: yes a loop like that was the basic idea of what I had in mind. Just don;t know if there is an easier way, but suits my purpose.

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič The edit above should fulfil your requirements.

Comment: The validation is done later on in the DB itself. This suits what I needed, thanks

Comment: I made it reusable, feel free to check that out. Happy to help

Comment: Note that the `Object.assign()` function in newer JavaScript runtimes will basically do exactly this, as would the old jQuery `$.extend()`.

Comment: Did think of $.extend @Pointy but wasn't in question, nice one regarding Object.assign() - Would be fine since the question I assume is related to a node/express app (req.body)